# AccelStepper Library: How do I go to a position without decelerating?

Tags: motor, stepper

When I make the motor move at a certain distance with setMaxSpeed(), setAcceleration(), and moveTo(), it always accelerates and decelerates. Is there a way to disable the deceleration?

Comment: Acceleration and deceleration causes less mechanical stress. Why don't you want that?

Comment: Because I am trying to make it move in accordance to a set of acceleration data from an earthquake, and it seems weird that per value of acceleration (and distance from double integration), it accelerates and decelerates (and if the differences are too low, the motor can easily be heard vibrating)

Answer (score 1):

AccelStepper, as hinted by the name, uses acceleration always. By setting the acceleration high, you reduce the amount of time spent accelerating to the set speed.

`setAcceleration()` sets the rate in steps per second per second. If your MaxSpeed is 200 steps per second, then setting the acceleration to 200*10 means all acceleration is over in 1/10 second. You can go higher, etc.